# autocmd buffer local mapping if not *.py file

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, autocmd

As the title stated

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile not-py-file nnoremap <buffer> <F3> :call some_func<CR>
```

is what I want to acheive, but I don't know how to implement that `not-py-file` logic.
Any help?

Comment: Here `py-file` mean filename ends with `.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is to create the mapping for *all* files, and then remove it for `*.py` files:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * nnoremap <buffer> <F3> :call some_func<CR>
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py nunmap <buffer> <F3>
```

Vim executes autocommands in the order they are created (See `:help :autocmd`), so the two commands will always run in the correct order.

If that seems inelegant to you, you could instead have your autocommand check the filetype before it creates the mapping:

```
function! CreateNonPyMapping(extension)
  if a:extension !=? 'py'
    nnoremap <buffer> <F3> :call some_func<CR>
  endif
endfunction

augroup NonPyMapping
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * call CreateNonPyMapping(expand('<afile>:e'))
augroup END
```

Comment: Many thx, saved my time. The first solution is quite decent, and second one more extensible and might be preferred if `.vimrc` sourced more than once.

Comment: what about `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.*\(.py\)\@<! ...`?

Comment: @Mass I had no idea you could do that! Looking at `:help file-pattern` I realise I had always glossed over: `\   special meaning like in a pattern`. Does that mean you can use literally any regular expression element that begins with a `\ ` in a file pattern?!

Comment: Just about- internally vim uses `glob2regpat()` on the pattern which turns `.` into `\.`, `*` into `.*`, among other things, but then it's used as a regular regex.  Most pattern elements like `\@<!` simply pass through; you just have to be careful of the translation.  On the other hand, I'm not sure which approach is actually faster and yours is certainly less difficult to understand.